# Is it wrong to ask lots of questions and answer none?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it considered rude if you only ask Questions but almost never answer one yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47482/is-it-considered-rude-if-you-only-ask-questions-but-almost-never-answer-one-your)

Is it wrong to ask lots of questions, and not really answer any? I try to answer as many questions as possible to "give back", but I find I don't know much. I always choose the correct answer and upvote good answers.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47482/is-it-considered-rude-if-you-only-ask-questions-but-almost-never-answer-one-yours

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nope, not wrong at all!

As long as you indeed choose a correct answer and up-vote the good answers, there's no problem in asking *a lot* of questions.

Especially if they are genuine questions which you actually want to know the answer for. Some people just ask questions for the rep, even if they already know the answer. And that in itself even isn't *wrong* if the question doesn't exist yet, and can be of use for future visitors. It's only wrong when they are blatant dupes, or just silly questions.

Comment: Agreed. Also, a well-crafted question is a contribution to the community as well.

Comment: My questions are often...newbie questions.

Comment: @Sam still, they are mostly legible, well spelled and understandable. In my book, that makes them fine questions, and there is no need to be worried about giving back. You may automatically be starting to contribute the more you learn, because you will see more and more questions to which you know an answer. But nice of you to ask!

Comment: I can tell you for a fact you don't get much rep for asking. Maybe this was before upvotes on questions were worth 5 instead of the 10 on answers. Also questions are not upvoted much which makes it worse (1/2 rep * .3x likelyhood of getting upvoted = 15% rep of what an answer would get)

Answer (score 2):

Good questions are the **driving force** behind SO system.
SO accumulates and organized its members' knowledge *around* the questions.
A good question is like a small seed planted in fertile soil: it will grow up to be a very good answer and assist to many other people.

So, go ahead and continue asking! You help SO grow!