# Is it bad form to not answer questions?

Tags: discussion, answers

Put simply, I ask far more questions than I answer.

Not for any lack of motivation or interest, I put a good deal of effort into questions and answers making sure they are well explained and that I've done my own research beforehand; it's just that typically by the time I've come up with a solution the question has already been answered.

On top of that, frankly the people answering have far more specialized knowledge in their respective sections, and so I feel like my answers would only be muddying the page up.

I do -look- for questions that have been left alone, or that could use help and provide a fair answer, but for the most part I use the site to get practiced opinions as to the best methodology to accomplish a given task.

Even with my questions it's not so much that I couldn't -find- the answer, but that I want a persons opinion on how to implement it, and not a reference page with an agnostic list of functions.

Just curious if it's considered bad form to have a much higher Q-2-A ratio.

Comment: See: [Is it considered rude if you only ask Questions but almost never answer one yourself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47482/is-it-considered-rude-if-you-only-ask-questions-but-almost-never-answer-one-yours). If you're producing good quality questions and helping the system, then it's fine to be primarily asking questions instead of answering. After all, someone has to provide the material for others to answer. ♪

Comment: Heh, I figured there was a question like this out there, but boolean technology failed me. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: Agh, this _is_ a dupe. I blame being rusty again. Funny how the people who worry the most about whether they're behaving appropriately are the ones who have the least to worry about... but that's natural too, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why it should be a bad idea at all. Heck, if people didn't post many questions, I'd be pretty bored on SO :)

If you're putting effort into asking *good* questions (making sure they're not duplicate, maybe following [my suggestions](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)) then I can't see what anyone would have against that.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people feel this way, myself included. But it's totally natural for the ratio to be unbalanced. Knowing less about a topic means that you can't answer as many questions, *and* that you have more questions to ask.

The reverse is also true: the more you learn, the more questions you'll be able to answer, *and* the fewer questions you'll have for asking others.