# Am I obligated to answer questions before asking one?

Tags: support, questions, answers, asking-questions

I am new here and I have a question. Can I just ask questions on this community or do I have to answer other peoples questions too? I feel awkward when I just ask but not being able to help anyone.

Comment: How dare you ask this question on meta before answering another one?

Comment: Also see [Is it considered rude if you only ask Questions but almost never answer one yourself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47482/187824)

Comment: @JoachimSauer I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @user2154695: Well, if it *were* a problem to ask without answering, then this question would be a problem as well ;-) I'm sorry, I thought about adding "(this is a joke)", but decided against it, since the answers already clarified that it's perfectly ok to just ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need people asking good questions to be able to provide answers!

Ask away, all participation is voluntary and you do not *have* to answer any questions. Of course, if you see a question to which you have the answer, don't hold back either.

Comment: OK, thanks. Sorry for the dublicate.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such rule that you can only ask the question or only answer the question. Choice is always yours. If you are fresher to some topic then you can only ask the question and if you have mastering in another topic then you can contribute by answering other fresher's question.

After all StackOverflow is run by **You**.

Answer (score 1):

Asking *good questions* is a service to the community. I cannot demand that anyone do it, and I could probably ask more good questions myself. But if you are so inclined, then please, *please* ask good questions. Whether or not you are also making answers is irrelevant to the goodness of making good questions.

Writing *good questions* (and improving existing questions, if you consider that to be separate) is fundamentally a way to contribute positively. Writing *good answers* is great too, but please don't be reluctant to contribute in one way just because you have not yet done so in another. Asking questions before answering them--or even asking questions and never answering one--is perfectly fine.

It's *possible* to be a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) ([related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)) but people who ask good, well-researched, well-maintained questions (see [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), [there](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), and [more links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87900/185080)) are fundamentally the opposite of a vampire (like [Karin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karin_%28manga%29)!). Good askers show how the art of creating questions is done, and consequently are even an active force *against* help vampirism.

(And whatever you do, please don't submit *bad* answers!)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly only ask questions. Just make sure they are good, on-topic ones, that fit the scope of the FAQ.

Don't hesitate to answer a question if you know the answer to it though! Answering also gives more reputation points than asking!

Good luck, and happy asking!

Answer (score 0):

Before he teaches to other, any professor had to learn.

When you'll feel you can answer, because you know well enough both a technology and the SO site, then you'll pay the community back. That's just how life works.